# In a WFP MahApps application, restoring "e.Cancel" to false doesn't work

Tags: .net, wpf, mahapps.metro

In the following async OnNavigating handler, restoring e.Cancel to false should have allowed the user to navigate away from the current page. Somehow the navigation failed unexpectedly!

```
private async void NavigationService_OnNavigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
 {
      var model = DataContext as ViewModel;
      if (model == null || !model.IsDirty) return;

      e.Cancel = true;
      var option = MessageDialogResult.Negative;
      try
      {
           var metroWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
           option = await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Form", "Quit?", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative);
      }
      finally
      {
           if (option == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
           //******Allow the user to move away********
           e.Cancel = false;
      }
 }
```

Could anybody shed some light on the problem? Anything related to .Net threading?

***Updated:*** 
   The problem has been inelegantly solved with the decision variable `_canNavigate`.

```
private bool _canNavigate = false;
private async void NavigationService_OnNavigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    var model = DataContext as ViewModel;
    if (model == null || !model.IsDirty) return;

    if (!_canNavigate)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        var metroWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        var option = await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Form", "Quit?", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative);
        if (option == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
        {
            _canNavigate = true;
            _navigationService.Navigate(e.Uri);
        }
        else _canNavigate = false;
    }
    else
    {
         _canNavigate = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how the Cancel property works, but why do you set it to true first and then change it based on the dialog? Wouldn't it make more sense to add an else to the if(option ==... statement, with the e.Cancel = true?

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the `e.Cancel = true;`? If it still doesn't work then you maybe have another EventHandler that cancels the navigation.

Comment: @NathanL Did you abandon this question? Did you solve it?

Comment: @FishySwede @haindl Thanks for your comments! Setting e.Cancel to true suspends the navigation. If it was done after `metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync`, the suspension would not succeed. This is probably because `ShowMessageAsync` is asynchronous and the dialog displayed is not modal -- the UI is still 'free' to function.

Comment: Seems like a good solution in your latest edit. You should post it as an answer and accept you own answer. This will help others with similar issues to find your solution.

Comment: @FishyWede Thanks for your advice! Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been inelegantly solved with the decision variable `_canNavigate`.

```
private bool _canNavigate = false;
private async void NavigationService_OnNavigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
   var model = DataContext as ViewModel;
   if (model == null || !model.IsDirty) return;

   if (!_canNavigate)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
       var metroWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
       var option = await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Form", "Quit?", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative);
       if (option == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
       {
           _canNavigate = true;
           _navigationService.Navigate(e.Uri);
       }
       else _canNavigate = false;
   }
   else
   {
        _canNavigate = false;
   }
}
```